# Сериализация non-serializable объекта, который содержит несериализуемые поля

Tags: java, hibernate, serialize, netty

Здравствуйте! Возникла проблема: необходимо отправить по сети несериализуемую имплементацию гибернейтовского интерфейса ScrollableResults с использованием Netty. С удовольствием применил бы кастомную сериализацию, но Netty из коробки работает с Serializable. Почему мне нужно отправлять объект именно этого интерфейса: необходимо написать автоматическую генерацию таблиц JavaFX по ответу сервера. Пробовал решения вида:

```
public class ScrollAllResponce<T extends DB_Entity> 
extends AbstractEntityCommand<T> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8151149290494368726L;

    private transient ScrollableResults results;

    public ScrollAllResponce(Class<T> entityClass, ScrollableResults results) {
        super(entityClass);         
        this.results = results;
    }

    public ScrollableResults getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream stream) {
        try
        {
            stream.defaultWriteObject();
            stream.writeObject(results);
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream stream) {
        try
        {
            stream.defaultReadObject();
            results = (ScrollableResults) stream.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

На что получаю java.io.NotSerializableException: org.hibernate.internal.ScrollableResultsImpl в методе  `writeObject(ObjectOutputStream stream)`
 Пробовал так же использовать в своей обертке не интерфейс, а имплементацию, результат тот же. Видимо, гибернейтовская имплементация содержит несериализуемые объекты. Так как же все-таки можно ее переслать? Возможно, я допустил ошибку на этапе проектирования и неправильно использую ScrollableResults? Заранее спасибо, буду благодарен любой помощи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем вам это нужно? Перенесите данные из `ScrollableResults` в объекты и их отсылайте, хоть по отдельности хоть листом.

из `ScrollableResults` вы можете достать только данные БД. Достаньте их и пересылайте. Пересылать объект `ScrollableResults` ни к чему.

Так же его надо закрыть, как скажется попытка обратиться к `ScrollableResults` на машине, которая его не открывала?